# drupal_http_request give 400 response code for working url

Tags: http-request

I have major problem while getting response. I am using drupal_http_request to get the response but I get 400 as response though url given is working... I tried Curl Http Request module to overrride drupal_http_request. If i do that, then I get response code as 47 and error is maximum redirect followed. If I dont use CHR module, then error is 400 but through fiddler, or by POSTMAN, response is 200Ok..
Any help on this?

Below is my code

```
$url = "https://lastpass.com/misc_download2.php";
$options = array(
  'max_redirects' => 20,
  'headers' => array(
  'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36',
  )
);
$check_url = drupal_http_request($url, $options);
```

print_r($check_url) is giving code=400

Comment: 400 is clearly a _Bad Request_ error. You are setting application/x-www-form-urlencoded but you aren't sending any data.

Answer (score 0):

drupal_http_request() has GET as a default method, you are requesting a resource with application/x-www-form-urlencoded which is only available on POST requests as far as I know. a fix can be as simple as:

```
$check_url = drupal_http_request($url, $options, 'POST');
```

Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/4.6